# Linux download wildcard URL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chef-infra, wildcard, inspec

Using my script I'd like to be able to go to Chef Inspec and download the latest version. However the URL they use has versions. The versions will change and eventually, if I hard code the URL, I won't be getting the latest.

How do I use the wget command with wildcards to always get the latest version and never have to check it?

Here is the URL they offer:

https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/inspec/2.3.4/ubuntu/16.04/inspec_2.3.4-1_amd64.deb

I just want it downloaded and autoinstalled, but when the version changes I'm going to fall behind.

UPDATE: This doesn't answer the question exactly, but works. What I ended up doing was using the Curl command. This gave me the end result needed:

curl https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -P inspec

Comment: VtC reviewers: This question asks for chef automatization *with wget*, and doesn't ask for some software!

Answer (score 1):

You should add their repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  Then you can use `apt` to update their software.

- [Chef Software Inc Packages](https://docs.chef.io/packages.html)

Debian has a tool called [`uscan`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/devscripts/uscan.1.en.html) which can download from URLs using wildcards, but this isn't the right tool for installing packages.